# What is the syntax to accept only numbers and ignore any extra signs like "%" as user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3. I want the user to input the interest and I know that they will answer it with a `%` symbol following it.

My current syntax is:

```
interest = input ('Enter the interest ')
```

(Does using `raw_input` help? It didn't even work somehow.)

Comment: regex is what youre looking for

Comment: depends, do you want to accept "12.111111111124149991 + 10 % qwerty"?

Comment: If it's just a simple assignment slice up to the end interest[-1]. If you are doing something that requires more rigour use a split + index or regex.

Comment: `raw_input` is only in Python 2. In Python 3, the function is just called `input` (Python 2's `input` is `eval(input(...))`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure the user will only input numbers I suggest using `str.replace()`

This will remove the % sign:

```
interest = input ('Enter the interest ').replace('%','')

In: 20%
Out: 20
```

---

Otherwise you'll need RegEx with python's `re` module.

This example will ignore any non-digit characters and will only output the digits.

````
import re
interest = input ('Enter the interest ').replace('%','')
regex_match = re.findall(r'\d*',interest)
out = ''.join(regex_match)```


In: 2a0ac%
Out: 20
````

---

Breakdown:

`import re` - Imports the `re`(Regex) Module

`interest = input ('Enter the interest ').replace('%','')` - Grabs the input and replaces the % with nothing

`regex_match = re.findall(r'\d*',interest)` - This will output all matched digits as a list.

The r'' just tells python that it is a raw string so it won't get parsed.

`\d` matches a single digit [0-9]
and the * just tells the parser to Match the expression before it (\d) until it finds no more results.

`out = ''.join(regex_match)` - This will combine all list items into a string.

Comment: Uhm, as a beginner, I still don't get how RegEx is helping here, still thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'll add an explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to parse out `%` symbols, you can use the `replace` function, like so:

```
interest = input('Enter the interest ').replace('%', '')
```

This replaces any `%` character from your input with an empty string (thus, removing it).

Answer (score 1):

If the input is going to be `10%` only, you will be able to do the following:

```
interest = input("Enter interest: ")
interest = interest[:-1]
```

If the user enters `10 %` for example, you could always do:

```
interest = input("Enter interest: ")
interest.strip(' ')
interest = interest[:-1]
```